# How to use the query for joins like left outer join, right outer join or full outer join for arangoDB

Tags: arangodb

Examples of arangoDB query for joins like left outer join, right outer join or full outer join.

Comment: Please consider having a look at "How do I ask a good question?" https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at this [article](https://www.arangodb.com/why-arangodb/sql-aql-comparison/), which compares SQL to AQL. It describes ArangoDB's own implementation of joins, among other things.

> Outer joins are not directly supported in AQL, but can be implemented using subqueries.